# Finding table values in watij using xpath

Tags: xpath, html-table

I am using watij to automate my UI testing. I have many tables in a webpage. I need to find a table which has a width 95%. It contains many rows. I have to find each row with different text say "running first UI test on local" as below adn need to get the td value "Complete". I am not ble to get the value but I get the watij address. Let me know how I can find this.

```
<table width=95%>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">
      <span id="lblHeaderComponent" style="font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;">Component</span>
    </th>
    <th align="left">
      <span id="lblHeaderServer" style="font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;">Server</span>
    </th>
    <th align="left">
      <span id="lblHeaderStatus" style="font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;">
      </span>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left"
        nowrap="nowrap" style="font-size:12px;">running first UI test on local</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:12px;">Google</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:12px;">
      <a style='color:#336600;'>Complete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left"
        style="border-top:1px solid #cfcfcf;border-bottom:1px solid #cfcfcf;"
        colspan="3"
        style="font-size:12px; color:#ff3300;">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td align="left" nowrap="nowrap" style="font-size:12px;">running second UI test on local</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:12px;">Google</td>
    <td align="left" style="font-size:12px;">
      <a style='color:#336600;'>Complete</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an xpath visualizer like [this one](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com) to assist you in getting the right expression.  It lets you see the results visually.

[image]

Using XPath on HTML assumes the HTML is XHTML - in other words it must be well-formed XML.